# Why does calling MessageBox.Show() affects the visibility of other Forms (and threads)?

Tags: c#, winforms, visibility, messagebox

From a console app which has no window (`ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`) I need to start and display a Form (yes - I know this is bad design which should be avoided).

My first intent was the following code:

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
                            {
                                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                                Application.Run(new MyCustomMessageBoxForm());
                            });
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.IsBackground = false;
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```

This does **not** work: The form will be created, but is hidden. You manually need to set `Visible` to `true` to make it work as expected (see answer of [Show Form from hidden console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605988/show-form-from-hidden-console-application)).

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
                            {
                                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                                Application.Run(new MyCustomMessageBoxForm { Visible = true }); //Note the change
                            });
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.IsBackground = false;
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```

Neither the answer nor I have an explanation why you have to set the visibility explicitly – in a 'normal' console app (with a visible console window) this is **not** required.

Anyways, what puzzles me more is that after calling MessageBox.Show this explicit set is no longer required to make it work - even more, it doesn’t matter where in the application MessageBox.Show is called (whether it's the same thread or not), so both samples below work as expected:

```
MessageBox.Show("test"); // Note: called on other thread
var thread = new Thread(() =>
                            {
                                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                                Application.Run(new MyCustomMessageBoxForm()); //Works
                            });
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.IsBackground = false;
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```

and

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("test"); //Note: called on same thread
                                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                                Application.Run(new MyCustomMessageBoxForm()); //Works
                            });
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.IsBackground = false;
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```

So my question is: Why does this happen - what (cross thread!) side effects does calling MessageBox.Show involve?

Note: I used .NET Framework, the behaviour might be different for .NET Core or .NET 5.

Comment: Something something MessageBox.Show() being evil and starting its own message pump and probably more, just wait for Hans Passant.

Comment: "From a console app which has no window (ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden) I need to start and display a Form (yes - I know this is bad design which should be avoided)."  So you don't really need a Console app?  Use a standard WinFoms app, but pass your own [ApplicationContext](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext?view=net-5.0) to `Application.Run()`.  This way you get an app that doesn't show an interface unless you want it to, and it won't end unless you explicitly kill it from code.  [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32909558/2330053).

Comment: Read the notes here: [Can I keep worker and GUI separate without cross thread exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61386769/7444103) (Console app with *interactive* Forms)

Comment: Also, [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,2632) and the code [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,6071) and [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,6132)